# onClick cycle through DIVs with same class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a script to cycle through DIVs (one at a time) that have the same class name. `.nextAll()` and all that fun stuff is completely foreign to me. How can I get this to function?

Here's how it should work. When you click the light grey box on the right, it should show the next `.hint` along with it's `hint-description`. Only showing one hint at a time. This should be an infinite loop. Meaning, after the 3rd hint, it should just start at the top again. Hopefully the jsfiddle makes sense. Please let me know if it doesn't!

http://jsfiddle.net/DzD5W/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
(function(){

    var $hints = $('.hint');
    var $hintDescriptions = $('.hint-description');
    var i = 0;

    $('.next-hint').on('click', function(){
        i = (i + 1) % $hints.length;
        $hints.hide().eq(i).show();
        $hintDescriptions.hide().eq(i).show();
    });

})();
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DzD5W/3/)