# Jquery reversing a loop

Tags: jquery, function, loops, onclick

Evening all,

Todays conundrum based from this thread:
[onClick Cycle through Divs...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959222/onclick-cycle-through-divs-with-same-class)

I have modified the loop for my own needs here:

```
<script>
var i = 0;
var $Showable = $('.content');

(function(){
$('#rightArrow').on('click', function(){
    i = (i + 1) % $Showable.length;
    $Showable.hide().eq(i).show();
    });
})();
</script>
```

I've moved the variables outside the function to only create them once on page load so i can use them for the other button which is causing me a headache.

So here's what i have:

```
<script>
    (function(){
       $('#leftArrow').on('click', function(){
       i = (i - 1);
       if (i<=0) {i=$showable.length;}
       $Showable.hide().eq(i).show();
    });
})();
</script>
```

This is my problem line i think:

```
i = (i + 1) % $Showable.length;
```

doesn't translate well backwards i.e. -1:

```
    i = (i - 1);
```

I have tried adding an if statement where:

```
 if (i>=0) {$Showable.hide().eq($showable.length).show();}
      else{$Showable.hide().eq(i).show();}
```

and i get it to work for 1 round then it blanks the page once you pass the 1st Div a 2nd time.

and the current if produces the same result where i'm trying to set the value of i to $showable.length if i<=0.

thanks for your help in advance.

To clarify two buttons (divs) 1 cycles forwards the other backwards through the same set of divs.

Robbie

Comment: anyone got a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Did it:

```
<script>

var i = 0;
var $Showable = $('.content');
var length = $Showable.length;
(function(){
$('#rightArrow').on('click', function(){
    i = (i + 1) % length;
    $Showable.hide().eq(i).show();
    });
    })();

(function(){
$('#leftArrow').on('click', function(){
    $Showable.hide().eq(i).show();
    i = (i - 1);    
    if (i <= -1 * $Showable.length) {i=0};
    });
})();
```

if (i <= -1 * $Showable.length) {i=0}; was the required